# Why does GridSearchCV in Sklearn not choose the best R-squared value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to tune the parameter for a lasso regression model in Sklearn, but I'm finding that the GridSearchCV does not seem to be choosing the best R-squared parameter. I find that when I test with other parameters for lambda, they have higher R-squared than GridSearchCV returns. Here is my code:

```
lasso = Lasso(random_state = 0,max_iter=10000,tol=1)
alphas = np.logspace(-80,20,101)

tuned_parameters = [{'alpha': alphas}]
n_folds = 3

clf = GridSearchCV(lasso, tuned_parameters, cv=n_folds,refit=True,scoring='r2')
clf.fit(feature_matrix,labels)

print("\nBest parameters:")
print(clf.best_params_)
print("\nR-Squared:")
print(clf.best_estimator_.score(feature_matrix,labels))
```

This returns a best alpha of 1e4, with R-squared equal to zero. However, when I probe the Lasso model manually, I get a different result:

```
clf = Lasso(alpha=1e2,max_iter=10000,tol=1)
clf.fit(feature_matrix,labels)
print(R-squared:\n{}".format(clf.score(feature_matrix,labels)))
```

This returns an R-squared value of 0.39 (as well as pretty much any alpha smaller than this). Why would this model not have been chosen by GridSearchCV?

Comment: You state the best alpha was `1e4` but you're passing `1e2` to the Lasso model

Comment: Yeah, the thing I'm not understanding is that GridSearchCV claims that alpha=1e4 produces the best r2 score (0.0), but when I pass in 1e2 to Lasso with the same data, I get a better r2 score (0.39).

Comment: Did scikit-learn throw a warning about the convergence of your algorithm? For a variety of reasons, it's likely that the optimization algorithm did not converge.

Comment: What is `clf.best_score_`? Does `cv_results_` shed any light?

Comment: It was throwing errors about convergence, but then I set ```tol``` from 1e-4 to 1 and that was fixed. ```best_score_``` returns -1.0005, and I'm not really sure what to look for in the results. It just lists out the error values but nothing very enlightening.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as an answer, but I increased `n_folds` to 7 to better suit my dataset and it seemed to alleviate the problem.